# How to start display a list-view from specific item position

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, getview

I have a list view of 300 mp3 songs and suppose song 52 is playing. So I want next time when user opens the list of song, the list row in front of him must starts from row 52 (while up and down are still rows). I tried using

```
public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

and also

```
adapter.getItem(52);
```

But both are pointless methods and dont take me to row 52. (These methods are what I used, but might not be the solution) Also I got no solution googling it. Please let me know if you guys can deal with this !!

A big thanks to you for listening!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This line will select n row starting from top:

```
listview.setSelectionFromTop(n, 0);
```

So for your case as you want to select 52  row you have to right following code on start of activity after setting your adapter

```
listview.setSelectionFromTop(52, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks it works well !! (Cant do vote up because of less rep)

Answer (score 1):

try this:
[link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29)

```
listview.smoothScrollToPosition(yourPosition);
```